# Why would anyone use a NSDictionary over NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

What are some situations where NSDictionary is preferred over NSMutableDictionary? I feel like it is always nice to have the option to change values in the dictionary.

Comment: There are countless times when you don't need to modify the dictionary.

Comment: immutable dictionaries provide better performance because the system knows it only needs to allocate a certain memory size to retain it.

Comment: also there's no literal syntax for NSMutableDictionary

Comment: There is a big difference between *have* and *need* the option to change. Basically if you don't need it, leave it. In many cases you can enable mutability temporarily by creating a `mutableCopy`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*You* might like the option to manipulate the dictionary, but you would not like it if *other* code manipulated it behind your back. An instance variable typed as an NSMutableDictionary would allow that very thing to happen.

The same is true of all the other immutable/mutable pairs.

Comment: Also, as you've been told in a comment, it is possible that declaring as immutable a value you will never mutate adds efficiency.

Comment: Thanks Matt, makes sense

Answer (score 1):

NSdictionary working like constant but in nsmutalbledictionary we can add or remove object at any where after declaration.Another point is in NSdictionary we only assign that means we only get new dictionary that you assign.......